# How to get a single uv island

Tags: uv

I have created a circle pipe and converted to mesh and get all the square uv. I want this all uv to me merge or to be overlap on each other to have a single uv island. I want to have a single texture on all island. With the snapping on and grab i can but they are 100 island. Any addon or suggestion to get a single island.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Preferably I would do this by setting custom seams and unwrap it from a certain viewport (orthograpgic camera top - left etc <kbd>5</kbd> on numpad and then the voewport of your choice). 
If you have a seameless tiled texture instead, you may just want to avoid uv mapping completely or use it afterwards to bake your textures on your model, which means that you will be in need of a very nice and well unfolded pelt.
So, if you tend to follow the second method (since you have one seamless texture) use the mapping node in your material node editor and in case you insist for a quick unwrap, use unwrap from viewport <kbd>w</kbd>